# Adding object to an NSMutableSet automatically when it's initiated... (iphone)

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nsset

I have this problem adding an object to NSSet...

The NSMutableSet *set "belongs" to main ViewController.
I want to add an object (Wall) to this NSMutableSet automatically if I add it to view in interface builder... Wall is a subclass of UIImageView...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

found a way how to do it :)

for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
    if([v isKindOfClass:[Wall class]]) [obstacleSet addObject:v];
}